# How to implement tags in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony

I would like to have a form for entering tags (like the tag `symfony2` in this post). Something like the field below would be great, but for starting it would be enough to have a text field with semicolon (`;`) or comma (`,`) separated values that go into an n:m relationship in a database.

Unfortunatly it is really hard to search for this, as virtually everything contains the word tag :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a bundle that does most of the heavy lifting for you...

http://bundles.knplabs.org/FabienPennequin/FPNTagBundle

You will have to implement the client-side form control (jquery based probably), but could use something like [jQuery TagIt](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/)

Comment: FPNTagBundle has no integration with CRUD forms. It seems hard; there is an [open ticket](https://github.com/FabienPennequin/FPNTagBundle/issues/7) from 2012-05.

Answer (score 3):

This may also be what you're looking for:

[How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might use the **MkTagBundle**:

https://github.com/Mykees/MkTagBundle

It contains also a seperate website for documentation here:

http://mykees.github.io/MkTagBundle

By the way, it contains a number of other bundles.